# Building .NET 4.0 project on Windows server 2016, Window 10

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

We recently need to upgrade our build server from Windows server 2008 to 2016. Because 08 is fading out

As we all know, Windows Server 2016 is installed with .NET Framework 4.6 and from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-10

- You can only have one version of the .NET Framework 4.x installed on your machine.
- You cannot install an earlier version of the .NET Framework on your machine if a later version is already installed.

The case is, we have many projects using

1. .NET 4.0 with EF 4.4.0.0
2. .NET 4.5 with EF 5.0.0.0

And some classes such as System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute had moved from EF to .NET from EF 4.4.0.0 to .NET 4.5 along the upgrade.

Therefore, missing .NET 4.0 results in:

> error CS0433: The type
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute' exists
>   in both ...\workspace\....\EntityFramework.dll and 
>   ...\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'

because it trys to use .NET 4.5 with EF 4.4.0.0.

My question is: we don't have resources to ask QA teams to have a full test on every aspects of our applications, but we do need to use the new build server. Do you guys have any other idea / thought thats worth trying so that the it can build?

Comment: Any changes in your source code should be tested even you don't have the incompatible issue. You cannot expect to run a Windows 98 app on Windows 10 without upgrading or testing. You may want to run a VM of 2008 on your server to make sure everything is fine.

Comment: after showing your answer to my boss, he finally decides to update the project. thx bro